# Change attribute value in a for loop in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I have an XML file with test steps like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<test>
    <card>
        <Description>data</Description>
        <Result>data</Result>
    </card>
    <card>
        <Description>data</Description>
        <Result>data</Result>
    </card>
    ...
</test>
```

And im using an XSLT to transform it like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project name="project_name">
     <TestSteps>
          <TestStep uid="1">
                ...
          <TestStep/>
          <TestStep uid="2">
                ...
          <TestStep/>
                 ...
     <TestSteps/>
<Project/>
```

My XSLT looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="test">
        <Project name="project_name">
            <TestSteps>
            <xsl:for-each select="card">
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                    <TestStep uid="$i">
                    ...
                    <TestStep/>
                 ...
             <TestSteps/>
         <TestSuite/>
   <Tsr/>
<Project/>
```

As you can see I want to change the property "uid" of my TestStep at each iteration of the loop but with my method it doesn't work it just print me:

```
<TestSteps>
    <TestStep uid="$i">
        ...
    <TestStep/>
<TestSteps/>
```

Does someone has a solution to change that property each step? Thank you.

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example. Your XSLT has many errors unrelated to your question and cannot be executed as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<TestStep uid="$i">
```

use:

```
<TestStep uid="{$i}">
```

or simply:

```
<TestStep uid="{position()}">
```

For explanation, see:
https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates